# How to set backgound image for a component in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, next.js

I look at this documentation , [Static File Serving](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/static-file-serving), it clearly state that:

> Next.js can serve static files, like images, under a folder called public in the root directory. Files inside public can then be referenced by your code starting from the base URL (/).

I already put an image file named `background.jpg` in `public` folder.

Then in my `pages/referral.js` I have the code below:

```
import React from 'react';
import backgroundImage from '/background.jpg'; // later I removed this 

const styles = {
    container: {
        backgroundImage: `url(${backgroundImage})`,
        backgroundPosition: 'center',
        backgroundSize: 'cover',
        backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
        width: '100vw',
        height: '100vh'
    }
};

export default class Referral extends React.Component{

    render(){
        return(
            <div className="cComponent" style={styles} >
                <h1 align="center">Some item</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Then I get this error: `Module not found: Can't resolve '/background.jpg' in referral.js`.

What I tried:

1. `const backgroundImage = require('/background.jpg'); <-- and tried
   this`
2. `import backgroundImage from '/public/background.jpg';`
3. `import backgroundImage from './background.jpg'`

All attempt above also get the same error.

I even tried to add a `next.config.js`:

```
// next.config.js 
const withImage = require('next-images');
module.exports=withImage({});
```

Then import in `pages/referral.js` like this:

```
 import backgroundImage from '/background.jpg';
```

Also get this same error: `Module not found: Can't resolve '/background.jpg' in referral.js`.

What I missing out here? Also can someone please give me an example about how to put a background image into a component?

Comment: const backgroundImage = require('public/background.jpg')

Comment: @bcjohn sir same error. `Module not found: Can't resolve '/public/background.jpg' `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to change your style because your container having your css to apply. **`style={styles.container}`**

```
<div className="cComponent" style={styles.container} >
   <h1 align="center">Some item</h1>
</div>
```

You can check and change your style css

```
<div>
      Hello
      <div
        style={{
          backgroundImage: `url(${Image})`,
          backgroundSize: "cover",
          backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
          width: "100vw",
          height: "100vh"
        }}
      />
      <hr />
      <div
        style={{
          backgroundImage: `url(/kittycat.jpg)`,  // coming from public folder
          backgroundSize: "cover",
          backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
          width: "100vw",
          height: "100vh"
        }}
      />
    </div>
```

For your reference [Live working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/cover-image-lxzw1)

Comment: sir, I using next.js , my backgound.png in public folder, but it keep giving me this error: `Module not found: Can't resolve './background.jpg'` I dont know why.. even I followed exactly the same to your answer

Comment: @ken now you can check live working demo...i created for public folder also....hope it helps.

Comment: sir it works now!!!!!! Now the problem is,why it work? It work when i change to `backgroundImage: `url(/background.jpg)`,`

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to import the image, you can just specify the path to it for the browser.

Assuming you have `/public/bg.jpg` you can reference to it in the code

```
backgroundImage: 'url(/bg.jpg)'
```